# Is the set $\{z\neq0:Arg(z)>0\}$connected

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Is the set $\{z\neq0:Arg(z)>0\}$connected, where $Arg(z)$ is the principal value of the argument.

(The principal value, is the value in the open-closed interval $(−\pi, \pi]$)

I think the set is neither open nor closed, actually it is equal to the upper half-plane minus the nonnegative $x$-axis, am I right ? I guess also it is connected, but how can I show it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that a path connected space is connected

Edit: Your assumption about the region being the upper half plane minus the non negative x-axis is correct.

Comment: ah OK, I just took the wrong definition, but it is also convex right ?

Comment: It is indeed convex, as illustrated best by @Timbuc's answer.

Comment: @OBDA My answer, by sheer chance, also answers about convexity...:)

Comment: @Timbuc OK, clear

Answer (score 3):

For any

$$\alpha\,,\,\beta\in A:=\{\;z\in\Bbb C\;;\;\;z\neq 0\;\wedge\;\arg z>0\;\}\;$$

we have that

$$p(t):=t\beta+(1-t)\alpha\;,\;\;t\in [0,1]\;$$

is the line joining $\;\alpha\,,\,\beta\;$ and you can prove $\;p(t)\in A\;\;\forall\,t\in[0,1]\;$ , so $\;A\;$ is path connected.

Comment: Well, in this particular case it fits *exactly* to the definition of "convex set" in $\;\Bbb R^2\cong\Bbb C\;$, but it also shows the set is path connected by showing a rather simple, boring path between any two points in the set.